# Wordpress: (un-)related post that is not in current post tag

Tags: wordpress

I show related posts with the same tag at the bottom of a post, but I also want to add one random post, that has not the tag, like "try this completely different thing".

I've tried with *tag__not_in*, but my code doesn't work:

```
$tag_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$args = [
    'post__not_in'        => array( get_queried_object_id() ),
    'tag__not_in'         => array( $tag_id ),
    'posts_per_page'      => 1,
    'orderby'             => 'rand'
];
$my_query = new wp_query( $args );
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Sorry, I don't really know how to code, I just try to understand Wordpress' code and how I can modify it.

How do I get the posts tag id into the array?

Update> This works:

```
global $post;
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
// just the test   echo $tag->slug; 
$tag = get_term_by('name', $tag->slug, 'post_tag');
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'tag__not_in' => array($tag->term_id),
    'orderby' => 'rand',
     );
  }
}
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you're getting?

Regardless, I don't think you need `'post__not_in'` because the `'tag__not_in'` will take care of that for you.

After that, I'd look at the `$tag_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;` and make sure you're assigning the value you want to that variable. Echo `$tag_id` somewhere and confirm it's what you want.

Finally, I think you need your `new wp_query( $args );` to be `new WP_Query( $args );`

Comment: That's exactly my problem, I can't echo the id, I can echo the name  `echo $tag->name . ' '; `, but not the id.

Comment: Use `get_the_tags();` (but do it while still in the post loop) instead of `get_queried_object()`

That returns an array of objects, and you might need to convert that to an array of ids for `tag__not_in` to work.